# Problems converting text from fixed length fields to json

Tags: json, bash, awk, jq

I have a working solution that downloads a zipped fixed length field text file from a clients sftp server, uses a password to unzip it, then runs gnu awk on the file to convert it to a pipe delimited text file, then clean up after itself.

Bash script code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ZipPassword=********
export SSHPASS=********
export WorkPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/
export ArcPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/archive/
export DownPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/down/
export InPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/input/
export ReadyPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/preproc/
export OutPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/Output/
export AwkPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/scpost.awk


cd $DownPath

sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - ****@*****.*******.*** << !
    cd /frommbi
    get *.zip
    rm *.zip
    exit
!


for f in *.zip
do 
    cp -v "$f" "$InPath"
    cp -v "$f" "$ArcPath"
    rm *.zip
done    

shopt -s nullglob dotglob     # To include hidden files
files=($InPath*)
if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then


unzip -P $ZipPassword $InPath*.zip -d $ReadyPath


for f in $ReadyPath
do
    export PathName=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/PreProc/*.TXT
    echo $PathName
    export FileName=`basename $PathName`
    echo $FileName
    echo $OutPath$FileName

awk -f $AwkPath $PathName > $OutPath$FileName

done



rm -f $InPath*
rm -f $ReadyPath*

fi
```

awk file content here:

```
BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS=" 3 2 2 18 5 9 10 10 10 14 16 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 16 28 6 1 1 3 2 6 2 4 3 2 30 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 3 3 3 40 6 5 6 20 7 20 2 6 13 6 6 6 32 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 40 2 6 20 30 11 12 3 1 14 14 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 12 28 30 8 2 1 8 8 8 8 8 10 12 8 130 1 7 65 3 82 512 528 1 "; 
OFS="|";
}
{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub (/^ */,"",$i);for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub("^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$","",$i);
}
{
print$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$53,$54,$55,$56,$57,$58,$59,$60,$61,$62,$63,$64,$65,$66,$67,$68,$69,$70,$71,$72,$73,$74,$75,$76,$77,$78,$79,$80,$81,$82,$83,$84,$85,$86,$87,$88,$89,$90,$91,$92,$93,$94,$95,$96,$97,$98,$99,$100,$101,$102,$103,$104,$105,$106,$107,$108,$109,$110,$111,$112,$113,$114,$115,$116,$117,$118,$119,$120,$121,$122,$123,$124,$125,$126,$127,$128,$129,$130,$131,$132,$133,$134,$135,$136,$137,$138,$139,$140,$141,$142,$143,$144,$145,$146,$147,$148,$149,$150,$151,$152,$153,$154,$155,$156,$157,$158,$159,$160,$161,$162,$163,$164,$165,$166,$167,$168,$169,$170,$171
}
```

Recognize that the field names are numbers here to enable mapping in a database later.

I have installed jq to handle the conversion from pipe separated data to json, but I haven't be able to get the syntax correct.

The modified bash script content is here in lines 52 - 56:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ZipPassword=********
export SSHPASS=********
export WorkPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/
export ArcPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/archive/
export DownPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/down/
export InPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/input/
export ReadyPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/preproc/
export OutPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/Output/
export AwkPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/scpost.awk
export JsonPath=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/JSON/


cd $DownPath

sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - ****@*****.*******.*** << !
    cd /frommbi
    get *.zip
    rm *.zip
    exit
!


for f in *.zip
do 
    cp -v "$f" "$InPath"
    cp -v "$f" "$ArcPath"
    rm *.zip
done    

shopt -s nullglob dotglob     # To include hidden files
files=($InPath*)
if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then


unzip -P $ZipPassword $InPath*.zip -d $ReadyPath


for f in $ReadyPath
do
    export PathName=/Users/administrator/Documents/Work/PreProc/*.TXT
    echo $PathName
    export FileName=`basename $PathName`
    echo $FileName
    echo $OutPath$FileName

awk -f $AwkPath $PathName > $OutPath$FileName

done
chmod 776 $OutPath$FileName

jq -Rn  --slurp --raw-input --raw-output \'
( input  | split("|") ) as $keys |
( inputs | split("|") ) as $vals |
[[$keys, $vals] | transpose[] | {key:.[0],value:.[1]}] | from_entries
' $OutPath$FileName > $JsonPath$FileName



rm -f $InPath*
rm -f $ReadyPath*
rm -f $JsonPath*


fi
```

Can anyone help? Before you ask, I am using this method for the sheer speed of conversion. My Mac Pro can convert 100,000 2850 character records in about 20 seconds and does so daily.conversion to json will speed the next step in the process considerably.

Comment: If the problem is in the `jq`, it would be better if you removed the rest of the scripts, and just provided input to `jq` and expected output.

Comment: The problem may not be jq at all. the best solution might be to code the awk file differently and convert from fixed length fields to json without an intermediate format. Perhaps I should have included that I was open to alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  Since you're using `input` and `inputs` (which is definitely the right approach here), you don't want to "slurp" the file.

```
jq  -nrR '
 ( input  | split("|") ) as $keys
 | ( inputs | split("|") ) as $vals
 | [[$keys, $vals] | transpose[] | {key:.[0], value:.[1]|tonumber}]
 | from_entries
'
```

By the way, you could easily combine the awk+jq steps into either one awk or one jq step.  Doing so would save a lot of unnecessary munging.  If you choose to stick with awk, I'd focus on shortening that ridiculously long "print $1, $2, ..." statement. (Would "print $0" not suffice?)

awk's FIELDWIDTHS is certainly convenient, so in the next section, a jq filter for emitting an array based on an input string and information about the field widths is presented.

#### Parsing fixed-length fields using jq

```
# Given a string, emit a stream of the fields defined by the array of widths
def fixedfields(widths):
  foreach widths[] as $w ({s:.}; (.field = .s[:$w]) | (.s |= .[$w:]); .field);
```

If your jq does not have `foreach`, here's an alternative implementation:

```
def fixedfields(widths):
  def do_while(cond; f; g): def r: select(cond) | f | (g, r); r;
  {s:., w: widths}
  | do_while(.w|length > 0;
             .w[0] as $w | {s: .s[$w:], w: .w[1:], field: .s[:$w] };
             .field);
```

Comment: The code at the top is generating an error I can't seem to resolve: 
    jq: error (at /Users/administrator/Documents/Work/Output/pCycle1219103821.TXT:2): Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 2 (while parsing 'C$')